# Comparing two lists of filenames that are not identical

Tags: python, list

I have a folder with a dataset in csv and txt files (one csv and one txt file for one experiment). I want to analyse them only if I can find both the csv and txt files, forming a "pair" (which is not always the case).

I've created two lists of files in the folder:

```
list_signal =  glob.glob(filepath + '/*.txt')
list_zvec = glob.glob(filepath + '/*.csv')
```

My idea was to compare the two lists and create new ones with only with the matching names. The problem is the filenames are not identical. The pairs look like this:

2013_09_12__14_12_06h_zvec.csv

2013_09_12__14_12_06h_signal.txt

2013_09_12__14_12_45h_zvec.csv

2013_09_12__14_12_45h_signal.txt

I was thinking something along these lines, but Python did not appreciate it  (returned an empty list, probably comparing the first 21 characters in the filename from one list to full length filename from the other):

```
for filename in list_signal:
    if filename[0:21] in file_list_zvec:
        list_zvec2.append(filename)
```

The order of filenames in the list is important later.

Newbie here, go gentle :).

Comment: "Python did not appreciate it": what does that mean, exactly?

Comment: It returned an empty list. My guess is it is comparing the first 21 characters of the filename in list_signal to the full length filename in the second list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a list of shortened filenames from `file_list_zvec`:

```
[f[0:21] for f in file_list_zvec]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match your shortened name `signal[:21]` with each item from other `file_list_zvec` list

```
for signal in list_signal:
    for zvec in file_list_zvec:
        if signal[:21] in zvec:
            list_zvec2.append(signal)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

This should find all filenames that occur multiple times (with different extension) in the directory:

```
import os

filelist=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
filenames=[]
for thisfile in filelist:
    filename=thisfile[0:22]
    filenames.append(filename)
files=set()
doubles=set( x for x in filenames if x in files or files.add(x) )
```

Not you can iterate through all of the filenames that occur at least once with the following:

```
for filename in doubles:
  # whatever you want to do with the filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need two lists? Just store a list of prefixes where all required files are present, then process that list. Also be aware that glob returns the fullpaths not just filenames, so [0:21] probably won't work.

```
## to initialize
prefixes = []

for file in glob.glob(filepath + '/*.txt'):
    prefix = os.path.basename(file)[:21]

    if os.path.exists(filepath + '/' prefix + '_zvec.csv'):
        prefixes.append(prefix)

## ...      
## then later on, when processing
for prefix in prefixes:
    processTxt(filepath + '/' prefix + '_signal.txt')
    processCsv(filepath + '/' prefix + '_zvec.csv')
```